# Duplicate counters are being passed to threads in for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is a sample piece of code for actual problem

```
//Dictionary to hold unique keys
static Dictionary<int, int> list = new Dictionary<int, int>();

//Worker
static void Do(int index)
{
    list.Add(index, index);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(
                () => Do(index));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The `list` does not always contain 1000 elements, because `index` being passed to `Do(index)` is duplicating and thread is crashing.

It looks to me that the problem is occuring due to following scenario

1. `index` having value 0 is passed to first thread
2. first thread's `Start()` is called, but the thread is not actually
   started yet
3. on next iteration, `index` becomes 1
4. now first thread starts and receives `index` as 1
5. second thread is created
6. second thread's `Start()` is called and thread receives `index` as 1
7. now both threads are trying to add 1 as key
8. one of them crashes
9. `list`'s count is short by 1

**Is this what happening in this case? What is the solution?**

Comment: That code shouldn't cause the problem of `index` being duplicated (since you are already avoiding a closure problem). However, `Dictionary<>` is NOT threadsafe and therefore the `list.Add(index, index)` is not safe.

Comment: Nevertheless, when I try this, I don't see any error.

Comment: What happens if you add `lock (list)` immediately before `list.Add(index, index);` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It happend twice that list count is 999 out of 9 attempts after adding lock. In actual problem, i am adding values to a DataTable and there are duplicates.

Comment: How are you checking `list.Count`? Are you checking it immediately after the loop has exited? If so, it's possible that the last thread hasn't yet finished adding the item to the list. Also, not waiting for the last thread to exit before accessing `list` is also dodgy due to none threadsafe code. For your actual problem, I would suggest that it is due to code that is different from that which you have presented here.

Comment: @MatthewWatson After various attempts, i found list count to be OK after waiting for 500ms. In actual scenario, though problem is still there but now i am not passing index anymore to avoid this problem

Comment: @MatthewWatson please post your comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code shouldn't cause the problem of `index` being duplicated (since you are already avoiding a closure problem). However, `Dictionary<>` is NOT threadsafe and therefore the `list.Add(index, index)` is not safe.

You can solve that issue by locking before you add to the list, like so:

```
static void Do(int index)
{
    lock (list)
        list.Add(index, index);
}
```

You also mentioned that the `list.Count` was not always correct. This is likely to be because you are checking the count before the last thread has completed adding.

You can test that idea by sleeping for a short while before checking the count.
(However, sleeping is in general the wrong approach to thread synchronization - but it's OK for a quick test like this. Just don't do it in production code!)

Answer (score 2):

As to why exactly this is happening I would guess Matthew Watsons suggestion about not waiting for the last thread to exit is probably correct.

But I would add that you probably don't want to do this by kicking off all your own threads. Parallel.For would handle this for you more efficiently and resolves issues of when everything has completed. e.g. replace your loop above with this.

```
Parallel.For(0, counter, Do)
```

Comment: I agree, `Parallel.For(0, counter, Do);` is the best approach for this particular problem.